# How to install monodevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

when i try it to install from ubuntu update manager i got the folling message:-

The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.
When I click on detail the followong message is appeared .So please tell me how to install this sowtware on my pc or tell me the other solution

> cli-common libart2.0-cil libgconf2.0-cil libgdiplus libglade2.0-cil libglade2.0-cil-dev libglib2.0-cil libglib2.0-cil-dev libgnome-vfs2.0-cil libgnome2.24-cil libgtk2.0-cil libgtk2.0-cil-dev libgtkspell0 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil libmono-addins0.2-cil libnunit-cil-dev libnunit2.5-cil monodevelop

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should update your list of packages.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Thereafter try to install the packages one by one on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xxx
```

Where xxx are the packages in your question.

If you haven't installed proper authentication keys look at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Under headline "Authentication Tab" you can find the way to install them or restore the default ones.